# Xamarin.Forms SendKeys

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that communicates with an external device which sends string data over bluetooth.  When data is received, I would like to trigger something equivalent to Keyboard.SendKeys so that if an Entry is focused, it will send the data from the external device into that Entry.  I'm already capturing the data and handling it in the app, but if the user has an Entry focused, it would be nice to send into that as well.  Or, is there a way to query for "Give me any Entry which has focus" and I'll just set the text value of it.

Comment: Hi, do you mean that want to find a `Entry` which has focus? If so, there is a proerpty `Entry.Focus` can check that.

Comment: `Entry.Focus` does not exist for me using XF version 4.7.0.1239.  There is `IsFocused` on an instance, but I'm trying to find any instance that has focus, not a specific one.

Comment: Yes, we only can use `IsFocused` of  `Entry`. But not too much understand need a focus property to deal with the logic.